# Magento dataflow profile - import products error - Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation.

Tags: magento-1.6, importexport, dataflow, configuration

I tried to save the **dataflow profile import products** but i can't. I just receive the error **"Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation"**

After some code investigation i can find this error is because of the following array of import and export file paths are missing are missing

```
Array ( [available] => Array ( [export_xml] => var/export//.xml [export_csv] => var/export//.csv [import_xml] => var/import//.xml [import_csv] => var/import//.csv )
```

The file paths are saved in Mage ImportExport config.xml as follows

```
<default>
<general>
<file>
<importexport_local_valid_paths>
<available>
<export_xml>var/export//.xml</export_xml>
<export_csv>var/export//.csv</export_csv>
<import_xml>var/import//.xml</import_xml>
<import_csv>var/import//.csv</import_csv>
</available>
</importexport_local_valid_paths>
</file>
</general>
</default>
```

Manual Trace

Mage_Dataflow_Model_Profile->_beforeSave()

Mage_ImportExport_Helper_Data -> getLocalValidPaths()

Basically the following method doesn't return any paths. Not sure why its so. Kindly let me know why this weird error happens and help me if you have some time for this.

```
/**
 * Get valid path masks to files for importing/exporting
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getLocalValidPaths()
{
    $paths = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EXPORT_LOCAL_VALID_PATH);
    return $paths;
}
```

- Magento Version : 1.6.1.0. C.E. Single locale and store.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @deeperDATA No, i didn't fix this. But from my code investigation i identified the Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EXPORT_LOCAL_VALID_PATH); doesn't return any values at all, its because of the store scope values.

Comment: I'm in the same position. Well, I'll let you know what I come across.

Comment: @deeperDATA If am not wrong, are you on multistore environment with different locale or timezone ? As well as did you install any extension which plays with magento scope for an example multi inventory ?

Comment: I am on a multistore environment but same timezones for each one. There are not any extensions that should be affecting it to my knowledge but this is a large project with several developers.

Comment: @deeperDATA It sounds to be a bug with Magento by default at least with 1.6.X Version C.E. As a temporary fix, you may return the values <importexport_local_valid_paths>
<available>
<export_xml>var/export//.xml</export_xml>
<export_csv>var/export//.csv</export_csv>
<import_xml>var/import//.xml</import_xml>
<import_csv>var/import//.csv</import_csv>
</available> for function getLocalValidPaths().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18262/discussion-between-deeperdata-and-haijerome).