# Alternative methods for exporting orders from Magento

Tags: export, migration

My real question has been asked before with no answers: [Magento dataflow profile - import products error - Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/magento-dataflow-profile-import-products-error-please-set-available-and-or-p)

Basically, I'm trying to export order data so I can import it into another install. Upon running the dataflow profile I get "*Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation.*" in the new popup window. As I couldn't find any documentation or answers that solve that problem, I'll move to my next question.

**I am unable to export with Dataflow. What other options do I have for migrating orders from one install to another?**

NOTE: My previous version is CE 1.7 and my new version is 1.9.0.1. I have been able to apply my 1.9.0.1 file base to the old install and that is where I can not export without the paths error.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose an alternative way of exporting data in magento is exporting the raw database in SQL from phpMyAdmin

[image]

Comment: I'd go one further. I would transplant the WHOLE database. Then remove all products/SKU's since if you want orders, you should probably move customers too